# How can I create an If statement with multiple conditions (not: multiple statements nested) in VBS?

Tags: vba, vbscript

In PHP, if I can compare a value against a list of other values on the fly:

```
$extension = "pdf";
if (!in_array($extension, array("docx", "xlsx", "txt")) {
  // do stuff to the pdf
}
```

How could I port this to VBS? Since I couldn't figure out how to create an array on the fly as in php, I tried and if statement with 3 conditions:

```
extension = objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path)
If Not (extension = "docx") OR (extension = "xlsx") OR (extension = "txt") Then
  // do stuff to the pdf
End If
```

But this does not work. The conditions are just ignored. Two questions:

1. Why are the conditions being ignored?
2. How can I, instead of using multiple `If` confitions or `If` statements, create an array on the fly to compare against?

Any healp is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way I know is (*boolean type*)

`UBound(Filter(Array("docx", "xlsx", "txt"), "pdf")) > -1` returns `False`

and

`UBound(Filter(Array("docx", "xlsx", "txt"), "txt")) > -1` returns `True`

as you can see the `Array("doc", "xlsx", "txt")` is created *on-fly* and I have replaced the `extension` you've used in your original question with two different strings (`"pdf"` and `"txt"`)

---

So, for example

```
extension = objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path)
' extension is pdf
' the below produces false which in your logic means YES it's none of them
If (UBound(Filter(Array("docx", "xlsx", "txt"), extension)) > -1) Then
  ' you assume it's pdf
  ' do stuff to the pdf
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `select case`:

```
extension = lcase(objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path))

select case extension
   case "docx", "xlsx", "txt"
     ' is one of the above
     ' do something
   case "zzz"
     ' its a .zzz
   case else
     ' its something else
end select
```

In your current logic contrast

```
If Not True Or True ...
```

and

```
If Not (True Or True) ...
```

Comment: +1 for an actual explanation why the OP's approach didn't work.